# Values larger than float64 despite using numpy to convert all values to float32

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I have two dataframes, inputs, and targets.  First the inputs.
[image: Inputs]

Now for the targets:
[image: Targets]

Here is the info from `inputs.info()`:

```
Int64Index: 2863 entries, 0 to 2528
Data columns (total 5 columns):
 #   Column         Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------         --------------  -----  
 0   fcreditlimit   2863 non-null   int64  
 1   bounce_cheque  2863 non-null   float64
 2   no_payment     2863 non-null   float64
 3   outstanding    2863 non-null   float64
 4   total_invoice  2863 non-null   float64
dtypes: float64(4), int64(1)
memory usage: 134.2 KB
```

Now I will convert all float64 and int64 to a float32 with `np.array()`

```py
X = np.array(inputs, dtype='float32')
y = np.array(targets, dtype='float32')
```

Now I have a function:

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_log_error as error
from sklearn.neighbors import RadiusNeighborsRegressor as Model

def rNN(X, y):
    xTrain, xTest, yTrain, yTest = train_test_split(X, y)
    model = Model()
    model.fit(xTrain, yTrain)
    
    pred = model.predict(xTest) 
    err = error(yTest, pred) # error here
    
    return err
```

And I will split the `inputs`, and `targets` with `train_test_split`. Then `fit` the model and `predict` with the model afterwards. Then use an error function to determine the loss. This is how I'm running the function.

```py
loss = [rNN(X, y) for _ in range(50)]
```

However, this error occurs

```
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32')
```

I am not sure as to why there will be a value that is greater than float32 despite me converting/reducing all the datatypes to a float32. I have also used `dropna()` and `fillna(0)` separately despite doing so. The same error still occurs.

I have done another test and used a `LinearRegression` model instead of `RadiusNearestNeighbors`

```py
def linear(X, y):
    from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
    from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error as error
    
    xTrain, xTest, yTrain, yTest = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
    reg = LinearRegression().fit(xTrain, yTrain)
    pred = reg.predict(xTest)
    err = error(yTest, pred)

    return err
```

I ran it the same way with a list comprehension

```py
loss = [linear(inputs, targets) for _ in range(51)]
```

And there were no errors for this. I didn't use `mean_squared_log_error` for this one because there was a chance negative values will be produced in `pred`. So to remedy that used `mean_squared_error` the on `rNN` function, and I also get the same issue.

I'm not sure how to fix this, or deal with this. Currently the only way I can deal with this is if I just used another model.

Comment: Have you checked `X` and `y` for NaN or *infinity*?

Comment: I used `dropna()` and `fillna()` on the original dataframe before I dropped any columns or started to filter the data. I also replaced `inf` values like this `csv.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)`. Then replacing all `nan` values with 0

Comment: "I used dropna() and fillna() on the original dataframe" - so you didn't check `X` and `y`, then?

Comment: `X` and `y` was made from the original dataframe. I don't see why they would have `inf` or `nan` values. I already use functions that can deal with `inf`s or `nan`s. `X`, and `y` was made from `inputs`, and `targets`. And those two were made from the original csv.